# What is the best way to secure files in AWS S3 with different permissions for different users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-cloudfront

I'm building an application which needs access to a large number of files which are going to be stored in S3 buckets, likely served with CloudFront if possible. These files should only be accessible by users who are authenticated. There will effectively be three types of permissions:

1. Files accessible by all users.
2. Files accessible by n number of arbitrary users.
3. Files accessible by only one user.

What is the best approach for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a perfect use case for Amazon S3 Access Point.

From the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/access-points/),

> Customers with shared data sets including data lakes, media archives, and user-generated content can easily scale access for hundreds of applications by creating individualized access points with names and permissions customized for each application.